# Predicate Expression filtring

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I write a c# LINQ predicate expression so that I can create a predicate that is similar to : " Select ... from customer where orders.orderDate > '01/24/2014' "
I am trying it like this, but not sure how to exactly construct it:

```
Expression<Func<Cutomser, bool>> predicates = PredicateBuilder.True<Cutomser>();        
predicates  = predicates.And(x => x.Orders.OrderDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
```

I am trying to have it consider all orders that have order-date greater than '01/24/2014'. The Customer class holds a property of type collection of Orders.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to create a join and a predicate for the second table in the join.
The predicate should be of the type of the second table, not the first.

```
var predicates = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>();        
DateTime specificDate = new DateTime(2014, 01, 24);
predicates = predicates.And(Order => Order.OrderDate > specificDate)
```

And then you apply it on the orders in your join clause:

```
IQueryable<Customer> source = database.Customers;
var results = source.SelectMany(
    customer => customer.Orders,
    (customer, order) => order).Where(predicates);
```

Comment: Close. But you can't use x.Orders.OrderDate. Becasue Orders is a collection. Using it like that would require an index like x.Orders[0].OrderDate.

Comment: ok. That would work but then how do I combine: predicates = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>(); and predicates2 = PredicateBuilder.True<Customer>();

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
var orderDate = new DateTime(2014, 24, 1);

predicates = predicates.And(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.OrderDate > orderDate);
```

Comment: Not quite, the condition will return true if it finds one Order with OrderDate greater than the date. I am trying to do it for all that satisfy the condition. Also using Orders.All() would not work. because that will only return true if all are greater than the date.

Comment: @Jay You want *to do it for all*, but not `All`? What do you mean?